# Can't access to bootstrap methods when including bootstrap via application.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline, typeahead

First of all, my gemfile

```
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'json'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'pry'
gem 'debugger'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'rest-client'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', '>= 2.1', :require => 'bootstrap-rails'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

When I have this manifest in my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

if I declare an input with the proper attributes, like this

```
<input autocomplete="off" data-provide="typeahead" data-source="['Alicante','Albacete']" size="30" type="text">
```

it works like magic, but I can't do this in my own js

```
$('#my_input').typeahead() 
// => TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'typeahead'
```

However, if I remove bootstrap from the manifest and I include it my layout explicitly

```
= javascript_include_tag "application", "bootstrap.min"
```

both ways work.

Can anyone explain me why? Maybe the uglifier of the asset pipeline is namespacing bootstrap functions? How fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `//= require twitter/bootstrap`

https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails

**Edit:**

Which gem are you using? twitter-bootstrap-rails, bootstrap-rails or something else?

if using twitter-bootstrap-rails then did you already call `rails generate bootstrap:install` to set it up?

Does changing the order makes a difference?  Try it like this

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Done, but the problem remains. I can't call bootstrap methods from my code neither from the javascript console of the browser. I'm going to update my question with my gemfile and the new manifest after your advice.

Comment: I'm using the one you have just recomended. https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved the problem.

It seems that this behavior happens when Bootstrap is being loaded twice (no idea why).
I can't say why that happened, maybe because I tried a couple gems of Bootstrap, but there was a problem with my auto-compiled assets in /public that are generated in production environment.

I run rake assets:clear (task provided by github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails) y all works fine again.